# Why do all my Java GUI apps have yellow text?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, gui

This started today.

[image]

Does anyone know what could cause this?

Operating system: Ubuntu 17.04 (zesty)

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this. It was caused by an experimental video driver. Here's the fix:

```
apt install ppa-purge
ppa-purge paulo-miguel-dias/mesa
```